Anselm of Canterbury's deductive ontology?
To my understanding on Anselm deductive ontology the conceptualisation of a totalitarian, monotheistic deity is what makes god infinite and eternal.
As the very modality, which stems from believe, is a hypostasis of pure infinity and perfection, as it's presupposed to a deity of that status, nothing can be above it.
Wouldn't this mean god is shaped by external forces? As the conceptualisation of this god is what makes him infinite...?

Not necessarily as Berkeley would perhaps reply if God's conceiving is nothing but your so called external forces of conceptualisation...


Anslem's dedeuctive ontology base on the conceptualisation of a totalitarian, monotheistic deity is what makes God infinite and eternal.

Not exactly. Anselm of Canterbury was a theologian whose motto is “faith seeking understanding” (fides quaerens intellectum).

This motto lends itself to at least two misunderstandings. First, many philosophers have taken it to mean that Anselm hopes to replace faith with understanding. If one takes ‘faith’ to mean roughly ‘belief on the basis of testimony’ and ‘understanding’ to mean ‘belief on the basis of philosophical insight’, one is likely to regard faith as an epistemically substandard position [...] The theistic proofs are then interpreted as the means by which we come to have philosophical insight into things we previously believed solely on testimony. But Anselm is not hoping to replace faith with understanding.

And Anselm opens his work Monologion this way:

If anyone does not know, either because he has not heard or because he does not believe, that there is one nature, supreme among all existing things, who alone is self-sufficient in his eternal happiness, who through his omnipotent goodness grants and brings it about that all other things exist or have any sort of well-being, and a great many other things that we must believe about God or his creation, I think he could at least convince himself of most of these things by reason alone, if he is even moderately intelligent.

This means that the monotheistic concept of God as infinite and eternal, that is "simply" the God of Christian tradition, is not deduced but is the assumption of Anselm's philosophy.


For me it unclear what you mean by Anselm's deductive ontology. If
you mean something different from Anselm's ontological "proof" then
please a reference from his work.
The argumentation of the ontological "proof" is simple and false:
The concept of God is a concept of maximality. And a concept with
referent is greater than a concept without referent. And therefore
the concept of God has a referent, i.e. God exists.
The trap of the argument has been indicated by a contemporary of
Anselm, named Gaunilo, and later by Kant. Gaunilo's objection for his part has been refuted by Anselm.

